# Disallow group of folders using robots.txt

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

I need to disallow the access without inform at robots.txt which folder is that.

In my case I have three folders `/_private1`, `/_private2` and `/_private3`.

I need to know if I use like above, I'm going to protect my folder against Google and others. How should I do that?

```
Disallow: /_*
Disallow: /_
```

Answer (score 1):

To disallow any directory or file whose name begins with an underscore:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /_
```

You should be aware that this does not completely guarantee that these directories will never show up on any search engines. It prevents robots.txt compliant robots (which includes all major search engines) from crawling them, but they could still theoretically show up in a search if someone decides to link to them. If you really need to keep this info private, best practice is to put it behind a password.